# Access a Managed Bean created by JSF in a servlet through a session

Tags: session, jsf, servlets

I'm trying to communicate JSF variables to a servlet, the way I found to do this was storing these variables in the session and then accessing them in the servlet. It worked fine in my first tests, but now, for apparent no reason, it's just not working.

Now, the servlet cannot find a session, it returns null. As if was not strange enough, it returns null just when i'm using Firefox and Chrome, if I use IE it returns the session correctly. I already restarted all browsers to restart sessions, but it still doesn't work.

My problem is: I need to communicate an attribute in my composite component to the servlet, here is what I'm doing:

```
...
<composite:implementation>
  <f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{Plupload.inicialize(cc.attrs.value, cc.attrs.servletPath,cc.attrs.runtimePreferences,cc.attrs.maxFileSize,cc.attrs.resizingWidth, cc.attrs.resizingHeight,cc.attrs.resizingQuality, cc.attrs.allowedTypes)}" />
  </f:metadata>
  ...
</composite:implementation>
```

Plupload is a SessionScoped bean, with its method "initialize" I pass all the attributes I need to the session.

In the servlet I do the following:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
  if (session == null) System.out.println("null session");
  plupload = (Plupload) session.getAttribute("Plupload");
  ...
}
```

The result when doPost is executed is "null session" printed in the screen and a NullPointerException throwed by line:

```
plupload = (Plupload) session.getAttribute("Plupload");
```

Of course, unless I'm executing it in IE.

Thanks in advance for any answer.